# 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded. Not upgrading (ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: python-3.x, upgrade, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to do `sudo apt-get upgrade exiftool` and the output is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libimage-exiftool-perl' instead of 'exiftool'
libimage-exiftool-perl is already the newest version (11.88-1).
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libgegl-0.4-0
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

I've tried `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` but that 1 not upgraded doesn't upgrade at all. What should I do?

Comment: SO is for programming questions only. Please ask on [ubuntu.se] instead.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem until recently

```
Fetched 3,013 kB in 7s (415 kB/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  php-symfony-console
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

I tried upgrading the individual package that was causing the trouble, but that just led me down a rabbit hole of package dependencies which were seemingly broken.

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php-symfony-console : Depends: php-mbstring
E: Broken packages
```

So I uninstalled then re-installed the 'parent package' that held the packages that could not upgrade. In my case it was the whole of php7

```
sudo apt-get purge php7.*
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```